# Using pivot table returns only indexed columns, omits pivoted columns

Tags: python, pandas, pentaho

I'm trying to pivot my `measure` column to have its values become fields.

Meaning `net_revenue` and `vic` should become their own fields.

In the picture below, the Input is on the left, and Desired Output is on the right:

[image]

I'm aware that `measure` has duplicate keys (e.g., `net_revenue` appears more than once), but `date_budget`, which I'm also indexing on, is different for that block of data. `date_budget` does repeat, but only when `measure` has changed, so we never have truly duplicate rows for the indexed columns.

**Question:** In Pentaho CPython script, when I look at output from the script, I get back only my indexed columns, but not the pivoted columns `net_revenue` and `vic`. Why is this?

[image]

**Script:**

```
import pandas as pd

budget['monthly_budget_phasing'] = pd.to_numeric(budget['monthly_budget_phasing'], errors='coerce')

# Perform the pivot.
budget = pd.pivot_table(budget,
    values='monthly_budget_phasing',
    index=['country', 'customer', 'date_budget'],
    columns='measure'
    )

budget.reset_index(inplace=True)

result_df = budget
```

---

Sample Dataframe:

```
d = {
    'country': ['us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us'],
    'customer': ['customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', 'customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2',],
    'measure': ['net_revenue', 'net_revenue', 'net_revenue', 'vic', 'vic', 'vic', 'net_revenue', 'net_revenue', 'net_revenue', 'vic', 'vic', 'vic'],
    'date_budget': ['1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', '3/1/2018', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', '3/1/2018', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', '3/1/2018', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', '3/1/2018'],
    'monthly_budget_phasing': ['$55', '$23', '$42', '$29', '$35', '$98', '$87', '$77', '$34', '$90', '$75', '$12']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

---

Worked in Pandas with `aggfunc='first'`, but doesn't work in Pentaho. Pentaho is still outputting only `country`, `customer`, `measure`.

Pandas output from terminal:

```
   country   customer date_budget      measure monthly_budget_phasing
0       us  customer1    1/1/2018  net_revenue                    $55
1       us  customer1    2/1/2018  net_revenue                    $23
2       us  customer1    3/1/2018  net_revenue                    $42
3       us  customer1    1/1/2018          vic                    $29
4       us  customer1    2/1/2018          vic                    $35
5       us  customer1    3/1/2018          vic                    $98
6       us  customer2    1/1/2018  net_revenue                    $87
7       us  customer2    2/1/2018  net_revenue                    $77
8       us  customer2    3/1/2018  net_revenue                    $34
9       us  customer2    1/1/2018          vic                    $90
10      us  customer2    2/1/2018          vic                    $75
11      us  customer2    3/1/2018          vic                    $12
measure country   customer date_budget net_revenue  vic
0            us  customer1    1/1/2018         $55  $29
1            us  customer1    2/1/2018         $23  $35
2            us  customer1    3/1/2018         $42  $98
3            us  customer2    1/1/2018         $87  $90
4            us  customer2    2/1/2018         $77  $75
5            us  customer2    3/1/2018         $34  $12
```

---

Even though above Python works, Pentaho 8.0 CPython plugin is still causing issues.

**First I melt dates:**

[image]

[image]

**Then I unmelt measures:**

[image]

[image]

**Where are my net_revenue and vic fields?**

[image]

Comment: Can you post your sample data as dict ?

Comment: @Wen added above

Comment: @Wen found it, needed `aggfunc='first'`

Comment: @Wen still doesn't work in Pentaho. See above

Comment: @Growler - `still doesn't work in Pentaho` - what it mean? Wrong output? Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael see above edit

Comment: @Growler - Problem is with sample data from question? Also does not work my alternative solution?

Comment: @jezrael Well as you saw I had initial input file that had its dates melted, which produced the sample file you saw, which is then fed to pivot the `measure` field. I'm not getting `value1` `value2` as the `net_revenue` `vic` fields I want. How do I rename `value1` `value2` fields accordingly?

Comment: @Growler - Do you try alternative solution in my answer? Hard to know what is problem, I never working with `pentaho`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166410/discussion-between-growler-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Growler - I am going to home, so unfortuantely I cannot chat with you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need add [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
budget['monthly_budget_phasing'] = pd.to_numeric(budget['monthly_budget_phasing'].replace('\$','', regex=True), errors='coerce')
#alternative
#budget['monthly_budget_phasing'] = budget['monthly_budget_phasing'].replace('\$','', regex=True).astype(int)


df = pd.pivot_table(budget,
    values='monthly_budget_phasing',
    index=['country', 'customer', 'date_budget'],
    columns='measure',
    aggfunc='first'

    ).reset_index()
```

Alternative:

```
cols = ['country', 'customer', 'date_budget', 'measure']
#if duplicates, first remove it
df = budget.drop_duplicates(cols)
#pivot by unstack
df = df.set_index(cols)['monthly_budget_phasing'].unstack().reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
measure country   customer date_budget  net_revenue  vic
0            us  customer1    1/1/2018           55   29
1            us  customer1    2/1/2018           23   35
2            us  customer1    3/1/2018           42   98
3            us  customer2    1/1/2018           87   90
4            us  customer2    2/1/2018           77   75
5            us  customer2    3/1/2018           34   12
```

Answer (score 0):

Kettle needs to know columns, which every step produces before the transformation runs - that's why I don't think it can be done in Python (select * queries are sort of exception, but they too secretly get metadata before the transformation runs). The usual way to perform pivot in Kettle is to use `Row denormalizer` step. The step requires you to specify column names for unpivoted values, but if you can't hard-code the values, it is possible to pass them based on your data via `ETL Metadata Injection` step.

In order to pass values dynamically create 2 transformations:
the sub-transformation will get input data from the parent transformation and perform pivot operation via row denormalizer.
The parent transformation will read input data, get unique values, which will become column names, then pass these values to ETL Metadata Injection step. The injection step will fill the row denormalizer metadata with the column names and execute the transformation, feeding your input data.